# Start another node file, with NodeJS API restrictions

Tags: node.js

How can I start another NodeJS application (as a child process) and restrict certain NodeJS API files (Such as not allowing that NodeJS process to have access to `require('fs')` for example).

Also, if this is possible and I was to restrict access to `require('fs')` would there be any other way the user could access the file system? (Disregarding the via the command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

---

`require` is a global function that you can redefine in the scope of a file:

```
require = function(module) { return null; };
// OR
global.require = function(module) { return null; };
```

This change is local to the file you made the modification in, so you could not start a `child_process` with this file to "prepare" the environment.

Another idea would be to mess with the `require` cache. `console.log`ging the `require` variable, you can see it stores a cache of required files. You could simply `require` all the modules you want to make private and replace (**not remove**) them in the cache with other objects or empty objects.
Sadly... if your user knows how `require` works, he can basically clear the `require` cache and require the files again, rendering that solution impossible.

---

A potential solution could be to force the user to use a function wrapping `require`:

```
var myRequire = function(moduleName) {
  // Validate or refuse requiring depending on the `moduleName` value
  ...
  else
    return require(moduleName);
};
```

and check first that the user isn't using the global `require` function (maybe via a custom JS parser or something?).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect answer! I'm going to just force the users to use a custom function for using modules. Thanks!